# Response from google webmaster tool : The document has moved Temporarily

Tags: php, google-api, google-search-console

When i request to get all sites response in google webmaster 
https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/sites/

i am geting this response form webmaster tool

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/feeds/sites">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: And what is the question?

Comment: i need to get connected web sites details.. i got websites details before but now i am getting this response so what to do dude?

Comment: Did you break Google?

Comment: sorry i cant getting you dude?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google's docs say that link is old.

You may want to review the new docs, I think https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/sites/list may be what you are looking for.

To explain your error/confusion, yes it does appear that Google has turned that URL into a redirect loop. Not a good practice, but a great way to get people to stop using it.

ref: https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/v3/sites/list

Comment: dude i have doubt is v2.0 deprecated or not